# ZXing.Net cannot decode the QR code captured by Camera

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, zxing, emgucv

### Latest Info :

After reminded by **@Michael**, 
I **successfully capture** and **decode** the QR code by using the

> zxingnet-88246\trunk\Clients\WindowsFormsDemo
>
> EmguCVDemo (successful decode QR code in camera frame today)

I will try to compare the difference between the Demo code and my code. Thanks Michael, so happy to successfully decode it.

p/s: those sample codes work with **net4.0** zxing.dll but **not** the **net4.5** zxing.dll

---

### Old questions:

By using Zxing.Net, I can decode **original** image of the QR code encoded by ZXing.Net.

But when I obtain the image from **Emgu.CV capture**, it cannot be decoded by ZXing.Net even I
try to *crop*, *resize* and add *canvas* size.

But, the magic is the **Android QR code scanner** CAN scan those QR code even directly from camera capture. I tried to analyzed the Android source code but I found nothing special.
I wonder if the Android version one is using camera auto-focus function?

Below is my code:

```
DecoderResult decoderResult;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\testfunny678.bmp");
LuminanceSource source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap);
//
BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));

try
{
    //null Hashable Hints
    DetectorResult detectorResult = new Detector(binBitmap.BlackMatrix).detect(null);

    Result result = decoder.decode(binBitmap);

    //decoderResult = decoder.decode(detectorResult.Bits,null);
    //points = detectorResult.Points;
    //Result result = new Result(decoderResult.Text, decoderResult.RawBytes, points, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

    if (result.Text != null)
    {
        //QR_CODE
        //MessageBox.Show("format is: " + result.BarcodeFormat);
        MessageBox.Show("result is: " + result.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("bitmap is null");
    }
}
//com.google.zxing.ReaderException: Exception of type 'com.google.zxing.ReaderException' was thrown.
//   at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.selectBestPatterns() in d:\Temp\zxing-2.1\csharp\qrcode\detector\FinderPatternFinder.cs:line 602
//   at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.find(Hashtable hints) in d:\Temp\zxing-2.1\csharp\qrcode\detector\FinderPatternFinder.cs:line 238
//   at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.Detector.detect(Hashtable hints) in d:\Temp\zxing-2.1\csharp\qrcode\detector\Detector.cs:line 90
//   at qrcode.Form1.Decode3() in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\qrcode\qrcode\Form1.cs:line 139
catch (Exception e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

My code can decode this

[image: My code can decode this]

**Camera capture** like this

[image: Camera capture like this]

After **crop,resize and add canvas**, it becomes like this (*testfunny678.bmp*)

[image: After crop,resize and add canvas]

I added canvas at the first QR code picture because I found of the QR code **surrounded by black colour**, it **cannot be decoded** even by Android QR code decoder.

**Old version** of my code using **HybridBinarizer** cannot decode the first QR code.

```
        LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(GetRGBValues(bitmap), bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
```

My ultimate target is decode the QR code directly from camera (2nd QR code), but if I can decode the third QR code, I also feel happy. My friend tell me to **sharpen** the third image so that ZXing decoder and decode the third QR code.

By the way, I **can detect** the QR code existence (Found at points (23.5, 76.5), (23.5, 23.5), (75, 24.5))
 of THIRD QR code via this two function

```
    public string Detect(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            ZXing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(GetRGBValues(bitmap), bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            BitMatrix bm = binBitmap.BlackMatrix;
            Detector detector = new Detector(bm);
            DetectorResult result = detector.detect();

            string retStr = "Found at points ";
            foreach (ResultPoint point in result.Points)
            {
                retStr += point.ToString() + ", ";
            }

            return retStr;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Failed to detect QR code.";
        }
    }

    private byte[] GetRGBValues(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        // Lock the bitmap's bits. 
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        return rgbValues;
    }
```

But even I tried to use the DetectorResult.Points from Detect() function by **changing** *Detect() function* to **return the DetectorResult** for Decoder, it is still **fail** at the **decoder part** by having **null decoderResult**.

```
    public DetectorResult Detect(Bitmap bitmap)
    //public string Detect(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            ZXing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(GetRGBValues(bitmap), bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            BitMatrix bm = binBitmap.BlackMatrix;
            Detector detector = new Detector(bm);
            DetectorResult result = detector.detect();
            return result;
            //string retStr = "Found at points ";
            //foreach (ResultPoint point in result.Points)
            //{
            //    retStr += point.ToString() + ", ";
            //}

            //return retStr;
        }
        catch
        {
            //return "Failed to detect QR code.";
            return null;
        }
    }

    void Decode3()
    {
        //System.Collections.Hashtable hints = null;
        DecoderResult decoderResult;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\testfunny678.bmp");
        LuminanceSource source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap);
        BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source));
        ResultPoint[] points;

        ZXing.QrCode.Internal.Decoder decoder = new ZXing.QrCode.Internal.Decoder();
        //ZXing.MultiFormatReader decoder = new ZXing.MultiFormatReader();

        try
        {
            DetectorResult detectorResult = new Detector(binBitmap.BlackMatrix).detect(null);
            //DetectorResult detectorResult = Detect(bitmap);
            //Result result = decoder.decode(binBitmap);
            //null decoderResult here
            decoderResult = decoder.decode(detectorResult.Bits,null);
            points = detectorResult.Points;
            Result result = new Result(decoderResult.Text, decoderResult.RawBytes, points, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

            if (result.Text != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("result is: " + result.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("bitmap is null");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Any suggestion or correction to successfully **decode** the **2nd QR** code and **3rd QR** code with **ZXing.NET** QR code decoder is welcome, thank you.

Comment: First, I could successfully decode the first and the third version of the QR code with the current version of ZXing.Net and the WinFormsDemo. My main question is, why did you get such a distorded second version? You should try to initialize your webcam and EmguCV correctly. I used EmguCV in a demo for ZXing.Net and I never got such weird results. Please take a look at the source code of the EmguCV demo in the ZXing.Net repository.

Comment: The second one is result of my ZXing implementation. Please try to assume the camera is fixed and we may have problem of luminance,rotation,resize,sharpeness, reflection of sceen, display sceen not parallel with capture screen.feel suprised after saw your answer,will try the winforms demo now,thanks

Comment: @Michael if can please write your recommendation to use demo code or even just repaste it in answer ? I will vote it up and accept it, thanks. It is a only solution for me until now.

Comment: How did you crop, resize and add canvas?

Comment: @Blaise, those steps did not done in programmatically since I was testing the functionality of the zxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I could successfully decode the first and the third version of the QR code with the current version of ZXing.Net and the WinFormsDemo.
My main question is, why did you get such a distorded second version?

You should try to initialize your webcam and EmguCV correctly. I used EmguCV in a demo for ZXing.Net and I never got such weird results. Please take a look at the source code of the EmguCV demo in the ZXing.Net repository.

Comment: I tried both demo and they are working fine, thanks.